# Is there a method to edit the "start time" of a calendar event without the "end time" changing automatically?

Tags: ical

Running Big Sur but this has been happening for many versions of macOS.

Is there a setting/preference somewhere to change this behavior?

There doesn't seem to be an option inside com.apple.iCal.plist. There used to be an ical debug menu option but that is no longer.

When changing the "start time" of an event the "end time" is automatically changed to keep the event duration the same. As far as I know I never prioritized duration of events.

I then have to reset the end time to where I set it before the computer made the decision to modify it. Which requires that I check what it was before it was automatically modified. A lot of back and forth for a simple task of changing the start time.

Answer (score 1):

In either the Day or Week view, you can drag the start or end time of the event on the screen without affecting the other.  For example, a one hour event from 9am - 10am, dragging the start to 8am makes this a two hour event now without affecting the end time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to remember this. I am always using the app in Month view when creating blocks of future events.

Comment: Note: The cursor must be a split-arrow for this to work.  Meaning the cursor has to be on the very top or bottom edge of the event and a split-arrow before one click-hold to drag.